# AVG and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

I have a set of records from which I select and average various data, and group by the hour.  It seems as if this function/query does an excellent job of averaging as I am getting 744 records with no problems.  However from June 8 to June 16 it seems to skip the averaging and group by.  As massive as the data is I have combed through trying to find a reason why this might occur.  It seems as if the data in those rows are no different than the data in the other rows and there should be no reason for skipping of records from June 8 to June 16.  There are NULLS, but I would assume AVG would just skip this data? Has anyone seen this particular pattern of skipping records especially as it pertains to the AVG and GROUP BY function?

DATE FORMAT: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000
DB Manager: SQL Server Management Studio by Microsoft Corporation

Working Data Link(this data was averaged properly): 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Av--kLXVY_a3dHA5UjBKYXc3UmRhQW9RN0NGbXl1NHc

Non-Working Data Link( this data was completely skipped for some reason):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Av--kLXVY_a3dFZqX3RuYVNWYWpVemNmSS12bzhIOXc

Query used to for averaging and groupby:

```
`INSERT INTO AverageRawData(DateTime,
SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP,SCR1_NOX_LEVEL,SCR1_NH3_FLOW_RATE,SCR1_O2_LEVEL,SCR1_NOx,
SCR2_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP,SCR2_NOX_LEVEL,SCR2_NH3_FLOW_RATE,SCR2_O2_LEVEL,SCR2_NOx,
SCR3_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP,SCR3_NOX_LEVEL,SCR3_NH3_FLOW_RATE,SCR3_O2_LEVEL,SCR3_NOx,
SCR4_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP,SCR4_NOX_LEVEL,SCR4_NH3_FLOW_RATE,SCR4_O2_LEVEL,SCR4_NOx,
CAT1_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,CAT2_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,CAT3_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,
VOLVO1_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,VOLVO2_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,VOLVO3_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,VOLVO4_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,VOLVO5_FUEL_FLOW_RATE,
TOTAL_NOx)

SELECT MIN(DateTime),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_NOX_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_NH3_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_O2_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR1_NOx)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR2_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR2_NOX_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR2_NH3_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR2_O2_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR2_NOx)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR3_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR3_NOX_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR3_NH3_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR3_O2_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR3_NOx)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR4_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR4_NOX_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR4_NH3_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR4_O2_LEVEL)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),SCR4_NOx)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),CAT1_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),CAT2_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),CAT3_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),VOLVO1_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),VOLVO2_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),VOLVO3_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),VOLVO4_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),VOLVO5_FUEL_FLOW_RATE)),
AVG(Convert(decimal(10,3),TOTAL_NOx))
FROM jmusa_LOG1
GROUP BY DATEPART(DD,DateTime),DATEPART(HH,DateTime)`
```

Comment: Could you post sample data, desired result, and what you have already tried?

Comment: Presumably, something is wrong with your data.

Comment: *Has anyone seen or encountered this error before?*, we don't know what the error is, you need to specify and give us an example of what's happening

Comment: Answer: D. Not enough information.

Comment: Apologize I am very new to this forum.  I hope my edits have clarified my questions further.

Comment: I believe this database probably has structural faults, based on the SQL that was just provided.

Comment: Smandoli, can you please elaborate on what structural faults might exist? I must admit I am very new to SQL programming

Comment: Very helpful if you say what database manager program you are using (MySQL, Access, etc.) -- and add that as a tag, as well.

Comment: I have updated what you have asked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with an Oracle DB, try performing an NVL(R1_EXHAUST_GAS_TEMP,0) on all the columns where you see no data.

This is from docs.oracle:

> All aggregate functions except COUNT(*) and GROUPING ignore nulls. You can use the NVL function in the argument to an aggregate function to substitute a value for a null. COUNT never returns null, but returns either a number or zero. For all the remaining aggregate functions, if the data set contains no rows, or contains only rows with nulls as arguments to the aggregate function, then the function returns null.

As they suggest, using NVL should fix your issue.

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm

Comment: Use ISNULL() for SQL Server. Sorry for the confusion... here is a great example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Roberto, I tried the solution.  I still does not seem to want to return the average for the dates between June 8 and June 16.

Comment: Can you tell me the datatype for the DateTime column in your db? What happens when you group just on that field? Do the dates come up? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding of the data dumps you posted on google docs are for raw data or the resulting data from your query

Comment: the datatype is datetime in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 ... when I group just on that field I dont get the hourly averages I get all the times listed which I do not want.

Comment: Understood.. I'm just trying to narrow down the issue. You're original statement says "June 8 to June 16 it seems to skip the averaging and group by". I interpret that as, you don't see that date in your result set, right? If you only group on "DATEPART(DD,DateTime),DATEPART(HH,DateTime)", then you should see that June 8th on your result set, do you? If not, then that narrows down the issue. If you do, then we need to look into the # fields. Hope this makes sense.. One more thing, why dont you SELECT "DATEPART(DD,DateTime),DATEPART(HH,DateTime)".. I see you only select MIN(datetime)

Comment: Now when I do a simple select to select days between 8 and 16 in June, the dates do show up so there is no problem with the DateTime field.  I do see June 8...Thats a good Idea I will try that